# How do I change my email address for Git?

Tags: email, git

I was trying to configure Git (from the Odin project instructions) and I accidentally typed a wrong email. The username is correct but the email is wrong - it is a sample email.

When I typed a command `config --list` then it popped up my username and the wrong email.

How do I change this email address?

Answer (score 5):

Just configure it again in git, the new value will override the old one.

For the current project only:

```
git config user.email 'your.email@example.com'
```

For your whole Ubuntu user account:

```
git config --global user.email 'your.email@example.com'
```